# How to serialize java.util.Properties to and from JSON file?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, gson

I have variable of type `java.util.Properties`. I am trying to write it to a JSON file, and as well as read from that file.

The `Properties` variable looks something like below:

```
Properties inner3 = new Properties();
inner3.put("i1", 1);
inner3.put("i2", 100);

Properties inner2 = new Properties();
inner2.put("aStringProp", "aStringValue");
inner2.put("inner3", inner3);

Properties inner1 = new Properties();
inner1.put("aBoolProp", true);
inner1.put("inner2", inner2);

Properties topLevelProp = new Properties();
topLevelProp.put("count", 1000000);
topLevelProp.put("size", 1);
topLevelProp.put("inner1", inner1);
```

Naturally, when I serialize the `topLevelProp` to JSON I expect the result to be as below.

```
{
  "inner1": {
    "inner2": {
      "aStringProp": "aStringValue",
      "inner3": {
        "i2": 100,
        "i1": 1
      }
    },
    "aBoolProp": true
  },
  "size": 1,
  "count": 1000000
}
```

The above JSON result can be produced by using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) in a pretty straight forward way, but when it is fed the same JSON string to desrialize, it fails.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String json = gson.toJson(topLevelProp); //{"inner1":{"inner2":{"aStringProp":"aStringValue","inner3":{"i2":100,"i1":1}},"aBoolProp":true},"size":1,"count":1000000}

//following line throws error: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 12 path $.
Properties propObj = gson.fromJson(json, Properties.class);
```

Tried with Jackson as well:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.PROPAGATE_TRANSIENT_MARKER, true);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
File file = new File("configs/config1.json");
mapper.writeValue(file, topLevelProp);
```

The last line throws error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.util.Properties cannot be cast to java.lang.String (through reference chain: java.util.Properties["inner1"])

Tried to desrialize from the string as follows and it failed with the following error:

```
Properties jckProp = JsonSerializer.mapper.readValue(json, Properties.class);
```

> Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
>    at [Source: {"inner1":{"inner2":{"aStringProp":"aStringValue","inner3":{"i2":100,"i1":1}},"aBoolProp":true},"size":1,"count":1000000}; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: java.util.Properties["inner1"])

How this can be handled?

**Update:** Following the [idea of cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730115/how-to-serialize-java-util-properties-to-and-from-json-file#comment70654979_41730115), found `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode`, can be used as follows:

```
ObjectNode jckProp = JsonSerializer.mapper.readValue(json, ObjectNode.class);
System.out.println(jckProp.get("size").asInt());
System.out.println("jckProp: " + jckProp);
System.out.println("jckProp.inner: " + jckProp.get("inner1"));
```

I think this can be the way forward for me, as I mostly have to read from JSON file.

Comment: (Not directly related to your question, but...) Quoting [the javadoc for Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html): _Because Properties inherits from Hashtable, the put and putAll methods can be applied to a Properties object. Their use is strongly discouraged as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or values are not Strings._

Comment: Addition to above comment: if you still wanna do that then write your own implementation for marshalling and unmarshalling

Comment: Why can't you just use a JSON object as a psuedo-properties object?

Comment: @SeanBright I have to work in a project that heavily relies on properties. I think it would have been better to use a proper configuration object (by a simple POJO maybe) instead, and that is in fact my fallback option in this case.

Comment: @cricket_007 Not sure what do you mean by psuedo-properties object. Any reference will be great.

Comment: Like just use `JSONObject` class as-is. Store actual JSON. Make a `JSONObject getProperties()` method, if necessary

Comment: @cricket_007 +1 for this idea. I found `com.google.gson.JsonObject#get*` regarding this. Is there anything equivalent in Jackson? As we are already using it, it would be nice to make more use of that.

Comment: @cricket_007 Found an Jackson equivalent, updated the question. Thank you again

Comment: I saw the Gson use in your question, must've skipped over the Jackson part.

Answer (score 6):

The problem you have is that you are misusing `java.util.Properties`: it is NOT a multi-level tree structure, but a simple String-to-String map.
So while it is technically possibly to add non-String property values (partly since this class was added before Java generics, which made allowed better type safety), this should not be done. For nested structured, use `java.util.Map` or specific tree data structures.

As to `Properties`, javadocs say for example:

```
The Properties class represents a persistent set of properties.
The Properties can be saved to a stream or loaded from a stream.
Each key and its corresponding value in the property list is a string.
...
If the store or save method is called on a "compromised" Properties    
object that contains a non-String key or value, the call will fail.
```

Now: if and when you have such "compromised" `Properties` instance, your best bet with Jackson or Gson is to construct a `java.util.Map` (or perhaps older `Hashtable`), and serialize it. That should work without issues.

Answer (score 2):

As it was said above by [StaxMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59501/staxman), you're misusing the `Properties` class and you're close about having heavy issues for using it like that due to lack of type information. However, you might also face the same case for weakly-typed maps. **If** it's a must for you, then you can use your custom Gson `JsonDeserializer` (note the JSON arrays issue):

```java
final class PropertiesJsonDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<Properties> {

    private static final JsonDeserializer<Properties> propertiesJsonDeserializer = new PropertiesJsonDeserializer();

    private PropertiesJsonDeserializer() {
    }

    static JsonDeserializer<Properties> getPropertiesJsonDeserializer() {
        return propertiesJsonDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        for ( final Entry<String, JsonElement> e : jsonObject.entrySet() ) {
            properties.put(e.getKey(), parseValue(context, e.getValue()));
        }
        return properties;
    }

    private static Object parseValue(final JsonDeserializationContext context, final JsonElement valueElement) {
        if ( valueElement instanceof JsonObject ) {
            return context.deserialize(valueElement, Properties.class);
        }
        if ( valueElement instanceof JsonPrimitive ) {
            final JsonPrimitive valuePrimitive = valueElement.getAsJsonPrimitive();
            if ( valuePrimitive.isBoolean() ) {
                return context.deserialize(valueElement, Boolean.class);
            }
            if ( valuePrimitive.isNumber() ) {
                return context.deserialize(valueElement, Number.class); // depends on the JSON literal due to the lack of real number type info
            }
            if ( valuePrimitive.isString() ) {
                return context.deserialize(valueElement, String.class);
            }
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
        if ( valueElement instanceof JsonArray ) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Arrays are unsupported due to lack of type information (a generic list or a concrete type array?)");
        }
        if ( valueElement instanceof JsonNull ) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Nulls cannot be deserialized");
        }
        throw new AssertionError("Must never happen");
    }

}
```

Hence, it might be used like this:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Properties.class, getPropertiesJsonDeserializer())
        .create();

public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Properties outgoingProperties = createProperties();
    out.println(outgoingProperties);
    final String json = gson.toJson(outgoingProperties);
    out.println(json);
    final Properties incomingProperties = gson.fromJson(json, Properties.class);
    out.println(incomingProperties);
}

private static Properties createProperties() {
    final Properties inner3 = new Properties();
    inner3.put("i1", 1);
    inner3.put("i2", 100);
    final Properties inner2 = new Properties();
    inner2.put("aStringProp", "aStringValue");
    inner2.put("inner3", inner3);
    final Properties inner1 = new Properties();
    inner1.put("aBoolProp", true);
    inner1.put("inner2", inner2);
    final Properties topLevelProp = new Properties();
    topLevelProp.put("count", 1000000);
    topLevelProp.put("size", 1);
    topLevelProp.put("inner1", inner1);
    return topLevelProp;
}
```

with the following output:

> {inner1={inner2={aStringProp=aStringValue, inner3={i2=100, i1=1}}, aBoolProp=true}, size=1, count=1000000}
>   {"inner1":{"inner2":{"aStringProp":"aStringValue","inner3": {"i2":100,"i1":1}},"aBoolProp":true},"size":1,"count":1000000}
>   {inner1={inner2={aStringProp=aStringValue, inner3={i2=100, i1=1}}, aBoolProp=true}, size=1, count=1000000}

---

### Type info injection

You could save some type information though, if you inject the type information in the result JSON. Let's assume you are fine with storing numeric values as not primitives, but JSON objects having two keys like `_$T` and `_$V` to hold the actual type (a class indeed, not any `java.reflect.Type`, unfortunately) and the associated value respectively in order to restore the real type of the property. This can be applied to arrays either, but it's still not possible to hold a parameterized type due to the lack of type paremerization for instances that are parameterized *somehow* (unless you can reach it via a `Class` instance):

```java
final class PropertiesJsonDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<Properties> {

    private static final JsonDeserializer<Properties> propertiesJsonDeserializer = new PropertiesJsonDeserializer();

    private PropertiesJsonDeserializer() {
    }

    static JsonDeserializer<Properties> getPropertiesJsonDeserializer() {
        return propertiesJsonDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        for ( final Entry<String, JsonElement> e : jsonObject.entrySet() ) {
            properties.put(e.getKey(), parseValue(context, e.getValue()));
        }
        return properties;
    }

    private static Object parseValue(final JsonDeserializationContext context, final JsonElement valueElement) {
        if ( valueElement instanceof JsonObject ) {
            return context.deserialize(valueElement, Properties.class);
        }
        if ( valueElement instanceof JsonPrimitive ) {
            final JsonPrimitive valuePrimitive = valueElement.getAsJsonPrimitive();
            if ( valuePrimitive.isBoolean() ) {
                return context.deserialize(valueElement, Boolean.class);
            }
            if ( valuePrimitive.isNumber() ) {
                return context.deserialize(valueElement, Number.class); // depends on the JSON literal due to the lack of real number type info
            }
            if ( valuePrimitive.isString() ) {
                return context.deserialize(valueElement, String.class);
            }
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
        if ( valueElement instanceof JsonArray ) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Arrays are unsupported due to lack of type information (a generic list or a concrete type array?)");
        }
        if ( valueElement instanceof JsonNull ) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Nulls cannot be deserialized");
        }
        throw new AssertionError("Must never happen");
    }

}

final class TypeAwarePropertiesSerializer
        implements JsonSerializer<Properties> {

    private static final JsonSerializer<Properties> typeAwarePropertiesSerializer = new TypeAwarePropertiesSerializer();

    private TypeAwarePropertiesSerializer() {
    }

    static JsonSerializer<Properties> getTypeAwarePropertiesSerializer() {
        return typeAwarePropertiesSerializer;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final Properties properties, final Type type, final JsonSerializationContext context) {
        final JsonObject propertiesJson = new JsonObject();
        for ( final Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet() ) {
            final String property = (String) entry.getKey();
            final Object value = entry.getValue();
            if ( value instanceof Boolean ) {
                propertiesJson.addProperty(property, (Boolean) value);
            } else if ( value instanceof Character ) {
                propertiesJson.addProperty(property, (Character) value);
            } else if ( value instanceof Number ) {
                final JsonObject wrapperJson = newWrapperJson(value);
                wrapperJson.addProperty("_$V", (Number) value);
                propertiesJson.add(property, wrapperJson);
            } else if ( value instanceof String ) {
                propertiesJson.addProperty(property, (String) value);
            } else if ( value instanceof Properties || value instanceof Collection || value instanceof Map ) {
                propertiesJson.add(property, context.serialize(value));
            } else if ( value != null ) {
                final Class<?> aClass = value.getClass();
                if ( aClass.isArray() ) {
                    final JsonObject wrapperJson = newWrapperJson(value);
                    wrapperJson.add("_$V", context.serialize(value));
                    propertiesJson.add(property, wrapperJson);
                } else {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot process: " + value);
                }
            } else /* now the value is always null, Properties cannot hold nulls */ {
                throw new AssertionError("Must never happen");
            }
        }
        return propertiesJson;
    }

    private static JsonObject newWrapperJson(final Object value) {
        final JsonObject wrapperJson = new JsonObject();
        wrapperJson.addProperty("_$T", value.getClass().getName());
        return wrapperJson;
    }

}

final class TypeAwarePropertiesDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<Properties> {

    private static final JsonDeserializer<Properties> typeAwarePropertiesDeserializer = new TypeAwarePropertiesDeserializer();

    private TypeAwarePropertiesDeserializer() {
    }

    static JsonDeserializer<Properties> getTypeAwarePropertiesDeserializer() {
        return typeAwarePropertiesDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            final Properties properties = new Properties();
            final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
            for ( final Entry<String, JsonElement> e : jsonObject.entrySet() ) {
                properties.put(e.getKey(), parseValue(context, e.getValue()));
            }
            return properties;
        } catch ( final ClassNotFoundException ex ) {
            throw new JsonParseException(ex);
        }
    }

    private static Object parseValue(final JsonDeserializationContext context, final JsonElement valueElement)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if ( valueElement instanceof JsonObject ) {
            final JsonObject valueObject = valueElement.getAsJsonObject();
            if ( isWrapperJson(valueObject) ) {
                return context.deserialize(getWrapperValueObject(valueObject), getWrapperClass(valueObject));
            }
            return context.deserialize(valueElement, Properties.class);
        }
        if ( valueElement instanceof JsonPrimitive ) {
            final JsonPrimitive valuePrimitive = valueElement.getAsJsonPrimitive();
            if ( valuePrimitive.isBoolean() ) {
                return context.deserialize(valueElement, Boolean.class);
            }
            if ( valuePrimitive.isNumber() ) {
                throw new AssertionError("Must never happen because of 'unboxing' above");
            }
            if ( valuePrimitive.isString() ) {
                return context.deserialize(valueElement, String.class);
            }
            throw new AssertionError("Must never happen");
        }
        if ( valueElement instanceof JsonArray ) {
            return context.deserialize(valueElement, Collection.class);
        }
        if ( valueElement instanceof JsonNull ) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Nulls cannot be deserialized");
        }
        throw new AssertionError("Must never happen");
    }

    private static boolean isWrapperJson(final JsonObject valueObject) {
        return valueObject.has("_$T") && valueObject.has("_$V");
    }

    private static Class<?> getWrapperClass(final JsonObject valueObject)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return Class.forName(valueObject.get("_$T").getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString());
    }

    private static JsonElement getWrapperValueObject(final JsonObject valueObject) {
        return valueObject.get("_$V");
    }

}
```

Now the `topLevelProp` can be filled also with:

```
topLevelProp.put("ARRAY", new String[]{ "foo", "bar" });
topLevelProp.put("RAW_LIST", asList("foo", "bar"));
```

if you have these special JSON deserializers applied:

```
private static final Gson typeAwareGson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Properties.class, getTypeAwarePropertiesSerializer())
        .registerTypeAdapter(Properties.class, getTypeAwarePropertiesDeserializer())
        .create();
```

A sample output:

> {RAW_LIST=[foo, bar], inner1={inner2={aStringProp=aStringValue, inner3={i2=100, i1=1}}, aBoolProp=true}, size=1, count=1000000, ARRAY=[Ljava.lang.String;@b81eda8}
>   {"RAW_LIST":["foo","bar"],"inner1":{"inner2":{"aStringProp":"aStringValue","inner3":{"i2":{"_$T":"java.lang.Integer","_$V":100},"i1":{"_$T":"java.lang.Integer","_$V":1}}},"aBoolProp":true},"size":{"_$T":"java.lang.Integer","_$V":1},"count":{"_$T":"java.lang.Integer","_$V":1000000},"ARRAY":{"_$T":"[Ljava.lang.String;","_$V":["foo","bar"]}}
>   {RAW_LIST=[foo, bar], inner1={inner2={aStringProp=aStringValue, inner3={i2=100, i1=1}}, aBoolProp=true}, size=1, count=1000000, ARRAY=[Ljava.lang.String;@e2144e4}

Summarizing up two approaches, you might want to eliminate the need of weak-typing and introduce explicit POJO mappings if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since I only needed a deserialization feature, i.e. generate Java properties for an incoming Json (in my case a REST endpoint), I quickly hacked this solution:

```
public class Configuration extends Properties {
    public void load(JsonElement json) {
        addJson("", json);
        return;
    }

    public void addJson(String root, JsonElement json) {

        // recursion for objects
        if (json instanceof JsonObject) {
            if (!root.equals("")) root += ".";
            final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
            for ( final Entry<String, JsonElement> e : jsonObject.entrySet() ) {
            addJson(root + e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            }           
            return;
        }

        // recursion for arrays
        if (json instanceof JsonArray) {
            final JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();
            if (!root.equals("")) root += ".";
            int count = 0;
            for(final JsonElement e : jsonArray) {
                addJson(root+count, e);
                count++;
            }
            return;
        }

        // leaves: add property
        this.setProperty(root, json.getAsString());
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is extending the Properties class. Another option would of course be to initialize a `Properties` object beforehand and pass it into the recursion.

I hope this is useful to someone :-)